# dhcpd on interface with multiple address and link labels (aliases)

Tags: dhcp

I had been running a dhcp server on an old version of isc dhcpd circa 2005, 3.0 something. I just upgraded to ISC dhcpd version isc-dhcpd-4.1-ESV-R6.

Before upgrading, the interface (eth0) had two address assigned to it, 172.16.0.1 on eth0:0 and 192.168.0.1 one eth0:1. But the actual interface eth0 had no address assigned. Only the subnet 192.168.0.0/24 was handing out address, and this worked fine. Now, after upgrading, it gives me the error:

```
No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
```

Which is true, there is only subnets defined for eth0:0 and eth0:1. I tried playing around with my config file, adding a shared-network statement, but nothing worked. Finally, I just assigned an address to the physical interface eth0 and it started happily.

I just want to know if its possible to get the old behavior as I have code that depends on it. Or do I have to assign a dummy address on eth0? The dhcp config looks like this:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
ignore client-updates;

subnet 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { 
}
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

    range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.4;

    option ip-forwarding off;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.168.0.1;

    default-lease-time 30;
    max-lease-time 60;
}
```

Comment: Is this an error (i.e., it doesn't start/work), or just a warning? Yours is a strange setup, but nothing illegal I can see.

Comment: It does not start. I now found some documentation stating that alias interfaces are not supported in dhcpd anylonger. So I am going to not use aliases anymore. See the note half way down:https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Configuring_a_Multihomed_DHCP_Server.html

Comment: Thinking a bit about it, that makes sense. If the server gets a request on eth0, should it respond via eth0:0 or eth0:1?